# strange character encoding issues with strings

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8, character

What would seem to be a simple operations is completely botched by the encoding here. I just want to check if the first character of a string is £. My php file itself is encoded UTF8-Without BOM. Thanks!

```
<?php
print "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN' "; 
print "'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd'>\n";
print "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='eng' lang='en'>\n";
print "<head>\n";
print "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />\n";
print "<title>WAMP</title>\n";
print "<meta name='Description' content='Website Under Construction' />\n";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<p>\n";

$temp = "£Hello";
$charArray = preg_split('//', $temp, -1);
// preg_match_all('/./', $temp, $charArray);

print_r ($charArray);
print "<br />First Char: $temp[0]";

print "</p>\n";
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>";
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => � [2] => � [3] => H [4] => e [5] => l [6] => l [7] => o [8] => )
First Char: �
```

Desired Output:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] £ [2] => H [3] => e [4] => l [5] => l [6] => o [7] => ) 
First Char: £
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I know it has a Unicode flag for regexes. What do you get when you do `$charArray = preg_split('//u', $temp, -1);`?

Comment: Yes, that works, but I really this line to work correctly: if($temp[0]=='£'){print 'Yay!'}

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The first item of the array will always be empty since the empty regex `//` matches the empty space at the start of the string. What about using `preg_match_all('/./u', $temp, $charArray);`?

Comment: I included the preg_match line to show that I was getting the same results two ways. Lets forget about that line. What I really want is to read the first character via string[position] syntax.

Comment: Does `if($temp[1]=='£'){print 'Yay!'}` work?

Comment: No. $temp[0] and $temp[1] both return '�' as exemplified in my actual output above. $temp[2] returns 'H'

Comment: Okay I have gotten it to work as follows: $temp = "£Hello";
print substr($temp, 0, 2);
Just select both characters together if (substr($d, 0, 2)=='£')print "Yah!";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$temp[0]` which is not multi-byte aware, try [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/mb_substr):

```
if( mb_substr($temp, 0, 1, 'UTF-8') == '£' )
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're sending HTML with appropriate content-type headers, I'm guessing you're running this through the Apache webserver. If not then please ignore me, but there might be a setting elsewhere in the server configuration to do this...

I've run in to this issue before, and absolutally everything must be in UTF8 mode for it to work.

Specifically here, I suspect you need to create a `.htaccess` file in the same directory as your script containing something like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

The restart Apache obviously.

Another note here, if you plan to use a MySQL database, you will also need to make sure that the connection is UTF8 encoded, by running the following SQL command after connection:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, I am running this on my local WAMP installation. I've added the .htaccess file but am still receiving the same results. I will be connecting to MySQL, so thanks for that tidbit. I will look into apache UTF8 settings further...

Comment: One thing I may have missed, sometimes using a <meta http-equiv...>  header to set the content type isn't quite enough, and you have to do something like this as well (in PHP):

`header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`